# HTML Tables Within Tables

Tags: html, css

I am a bit of a noob with HTML and CSS.  I am wondering what is the best way to:

1) Arrange 4 tables on a page in a square formation -- ie, each table is a quadrant, or

2) Put 4 tables within another table.

Any advice is appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: What about 1 table, 2 rows, 2 cells per row?

Comment: My advice would be to not use tables for layout. You can use [an UL element](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10790541/425275) to achieve this. **Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/U7WJ4/1/show/light/

Comment: To not. Tables are not layout tools, they are data structures.

Comment: But using tables for tabular data, even if it includes other tables is a good choice.

Comment: There seems to be confusion on what you want to acheive. Can you open Paint and sketch the layout, then upload the picture so we can visually see the layout you're after?

Comment: As long as you will put tabular data in that table, it is fine, but you should not use them for layout purposes. My advice is usually: Would you put it in an Excel sheet? If no, do not use tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the "Put 4 tables within another table." part of your question: as Jonthan Sampson said in his comment to your quesiton: create one table with two rows and two cells per row. In each of these cells, put one table within the td tags:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Table 1/4
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Table 2/4
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Table 3/4
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Table 4/4
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Jonathan was talking about using just one table, not four (and in your case five).

Comment: If you read his question carefully, you can see that he writes "Put 4 tables within another table." I'll edit my answer to clarify that.

Comment: That's not how I read it.  It looks like he wants one table with two rows, each with two cells, and nested tables within each of those cells.

Comment: Agreeably the question is open to interpretation, but I considered the part one and two of his question to be one requirement, i.e that he wants to have four tables in a square layout and secondly asks how to achieve this by putting the aforementioned four tables in one table. I think the downvote is unjustified as I answered that part of the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you're want to split the page to a 2X2 table best way is to use Divs (also easier to apply css on divs)

```
<div style="width:auto;">
  <div style="float:left; width:50%">
     x-1,y-1
  </div>
  <div style="float:left; width:50%">
     x-2,y-1
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
<div style="width:auto;">
  <div style="float:left; width:50%">
     x-1,y-2
  </div>
  <div style="float:left; width:50%">
     x-2,y-2
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Why_I_think_divs_are_better_than_tables

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, it sounds like you want 1 table, 2 rows, 2 cells per row.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Top Left</td><td>Top Right</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bot Left</td><td>Bot Right</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/gy5YC/

#### If it's layout you're after, there's a better way...

Please note that although this may give you the layout structure you're desiring, using tables for non-tabular data (think of a spreadsheet) is an illegal use of the element.

If you're attempting to layout a page, there are far better options available to you. You could use four `div` elements, positioned in a fixed fashion to the viewport:

```
<div class="panels">
    <div>Top Left</div>
    <div>Top Right</div>
    <div>Bottom Left</div>
    <div>Bottom Right</div>
</div>
```

​​​​​​
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/gy5YC/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> Top left Information Here </td>
    <td> Top right Information here </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> Bottom left Information Here </td>
    <td> Bottom right Information here </td>
  </tr>
</table>​
```

**JSFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/DNYwc/

Comment: The code you posted answers whether the first nor second part of the question ("arrange four tables in square formation" or "Put 4 tables within another table").

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be reducible to the question “to display four elements in a two by two formation, should I use a table or some other method?” Whether the elements are tables or something else seems to be irrelevant to the basic question.

If the four elements logically constitute a 2 × 2 table, make it such a table in markup. If the two by two formation is just the preferred rendering in some situations, then you could some other approach, such as floats, something like

```
<div style="float: left">A</div>
<div>B</div>
<br clear=all>
<div style="float: left">C</div>
<div>D</div>
<br clear=all>
```

This would result in a 2 by 2 rendering if there is enough width, but in a narrow window, A, B, C, D would appear in a 4 by 1 formation. If you use a table, then a narrow window would force horizontal scrolling. The choice really depends on which alternative is better for the content and structure.